# The difference between "pressured" and "pressurised"

Tags: american-english, british-english

I often hear people talk of being *pressurised* into
doing something, but I'm almost certain this is incorrect. A can of
deodorant is *pressurised*, or a tin of beer, since in both cases the release of pressure yields a delicious bubbly beverage (in the former) or a pleasant smelling, easily applied spray to eliminate underarm smells (in the latter).

If one feels a degree of pressure to do something, does that not mean
that one feels *pressured* into doing it, as opposed to feeling *pressurised*?

The term *pressurised* seems to me to be of North American origin (I refuse to use a z instead of an s). This seems reason enough not to use it, given that American English is a different language to British English, however I see it time and again in British English language media.

There seems to be little in the way of consensus on other parts of the internet so I thought I might ask here.

Comment: @used2025161 I believe it's a BrEng/AmEzng thing, "pressurised" being chiefly British

Comment: I have never (here in the US) heard someone speak of being "pressurized" into doing something.

Comment: Have you been drinking deodorant again?

Comment: @Brian, yes - I think we may need a question on the meaning of "former" and "latter"! And I must say that I have never heard that expression in Canada either.

Comment: @user2025161 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pressured+to+do%2Cpressurised+to+do%2Cpressurized+to+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpressured%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Elian https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt+pressurized&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20pressurized%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Brian I was making a joke, it was a lampoon, a simple lampoon...

Comment: @HotLicks Given the frequent spelling of it with a 'z' I assumed the word was of North American origin.

Comment: @user2025161 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt+pressurized+to%2Cfelt+pressured+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20pressured%20to%3B%2Cc0  ;-) "pressurised/pressurized" is BrEng. That's the term I was taught in school back in the early eighties.

Comment: @user2025161 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=felt+pressurized+to%2Cfelt+pressured+to%2Cfelt+pressurized+into%2Cfelt+pressured+into%2Cwas+pressured+to%2Cwas+pressurized+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfelt%20pressured%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfelt%20pressured%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20pressured%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20pressurized%20into%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Elian Thanks for the info... it strikes me that these links are pretty irrelevant given that Google books doesn't include modern media (newspapers, magazines and such) and neither does it have any information about spoken word. As our friend FumbleFingers points out below, the verb "pressure" itself is stated to be of North American origin according to the OED. Since AmE is rife with z's in place of s's I assumed "pressurized" was an American word.

Comment: People are pressured to do things they don't want to do. Substances are pressurized in order for them to take up less space.

Comment: @user2025161: OED's second citation for ***pressurizes*** is from *The Times* (of London), 1958, where it's spelt like that. I must admit I'd normally use ***z*** for that particular word myself, though I do tend to balk a bit at words like ***realize*** (and my ***spelt*** is purely to show solidarity! :)

Comment: @user2025161 - The difference between *pressurised* and *pressurized* is of no consequence other than the UK/US thing.  I was speaking of the difference between *pressurized* (or *pressurised*) and *pressured*.  As Ricky said, people are *pressured*, substances are *pressurized*.

Comment: Why is such a simple thing so complicated? Please don't pressurize me: I don't like enclosed spaces. [caveat: joke, which I always say so people don't start saying I am sarcastic.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150824?rskey=O0AVpl&result=3#eid) says ***pressure*** as a verb is originally a N. American usage, which they define as...

> *To apply pressure to, **esp. to coerce or persuade** by applying psychological or moral pressure.*

The more "standard" form ***pressurize/pressurise***, which can also be used with that specific figurative sense, is more likely when it's a straightforward literal usage relating to actual gas pressure (atmospheric, etc.).

---

It's worth noting that there are only 9 instances of [*"Don't pressurize me!"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t%20pressurize%20me%22) (AmE spelling) in Google Books, compared to 54 instances of the BrE version [*"Don't pressurise me!"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t%20pressurise%20me%22) (these numbers have to be considered in the context of an estimated 2,670 results for [*"Don't pressure me!"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Don%27t%20pressure%20me%22)).

Comment: Yes - I think people in Britain do say *pressurised* to mean that someone has been coerced. I agree that it should be *pressured* (or even *pressed*) - but I had assumed that *pressuris(z)e* was American-led.

Comment: @WS2: I'm quite happy using either word in the figurative sense. I have one of those new-fangled "isolated, hermetically-sealed" central heating boilers with minumum operating pressure higher than atmospheric. I have to ***re-pressurise*** the system several times a year via a valve to the main water supply (because of slow leaks, I suppose), but although I'd understand ***re-pressuring*** it, I don't think I'd ever use the verb in that literal sense myself. Having said that, I think we're at the absolute margins of "How precise is English?" here. It ain't really *that* precise.

Comment: The metaphorical pressurized meaning "having a lot of psychological/emotional pressure", e.g. of high-pressure jobs and workplaces, is found in North American sources, but yeah I can't find any examples of anything like "pressurized someone to do something" in N American media.

Answer (score 2):

As a scientist I must say that I find the figurative use of "pressurised" (in whatever spelling) confusing, as that term has a very specific literal meaning in science: to place  a substance or object under elevated levels of actual pressure (e.g., "to pressurise a container to 1000 bar" - while you could never say "to pressure a container to 1000 bar"). For the figurative use I would therefore always prefer "pressure" or "pressed" and reserve "pressurise" for the technical use in science.

Answer (score 0):

I am (almost) certain no one uses pressurize in the US or Canada in this way unless maybe they are originally from the UK. As a Canadian who lives on the border and watches both Canadian and US media all the time I have never in my 50 years heard talk of pressurizing people except on Corrie.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the term pressurized in British English. I do feel that it is on several occasions been used out of context. I believe that if you are pressured into doing something or not, that it is quite different then a can of pressurized air. With that said, it all comes down to your education throughout the world.

Comment: The Brits _do_ have a prior claim on the language, including choice of correct contexts where there's divided usage.

Answer (score 0):

I’m from the US but I watch a lot of British tv. I can tell you I have never heard anyone in America use pressurized to describe a person. I actually had to look this up to see why Brits do. Here we say pressured. As in I don’t want you to feel pressured. Pressurized refers to something mechanical.

Comment: Did you find out why Brits do?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another example of a person of British origin not knowing his/her own language.

1. Pressurise/ize is rarely heard in North America and sounds odd to us. I have only heard it in the UK or by someone from the UK and it was always in informal speech.
2. Refusing to use ize is a little silly. It used to be standard in Great Britain and is still listed as the preferred spelling. This is the case of North America retaining British spelling, not changing it. Like the word soccer - which comes to use straight from England.

Answer (score -1):

As best as I can tell, as a Canadian who has lived for 2 decades in the UK, pressurised as a word has become, in the UK, in the past decade and a half, a commonly spoken and written way of communicating an individual being put under pressure or coerced into doing something.
In the early 2000s I never heard this expression or saw it in print and it is now common enough that many people think it is the correct phrasing.